# API: s3:CreateBucket Access Denied when run a command 'sls deploy'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm a beginner in AWS and also serverless framework. I'd like to run PHP on AWS lambda function. So I need to set custom PHP runtime up using bref. So I run 'composer require bref/bref' and then I chose 'Web application' runtime.

I got this error when I run 'sls deploy' command.

Error:
CREATE_FAILED: ServerlessDeploymentBucket (AWS::S3::Bucket)
API: s3:CreateBucket Access Denied

I've already given S3 * permission for IAM user, user's group, user's role.

Please help me
what should I need to do and what is missing ?

This is my serverless.yml file

```
provider:
    name: aws
    region: ap-northeast-1
    runtime: provided.al2

plugins:
    - ./vendor/bref/bref

functions:
    api:
        handler: index.php
        description: ''
        timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-80-fpm}
        events:
            -   httpApi: '*'

# Exclude files from deployment
package:
    patterns:
        - '!node_modules/**'
        - '!tests/**'
```

Comment: Can you check who you are when deploying the solution? `aws sts get-caller-identity`.

Comment: Thanks for your care @Mornor Yes I can check who I am and user is right.

Comment: Does your Lambda have the role with s3:CreateBucket permissions?

Comment: Thanks for your care @Rishabh Sahrawat IAM user have a role with s3* permission. I thought it is enough. If not please help me how can i do it.

Comment: I notice something that I can not access S3 service with IAM user but I can when switch role. I am not administrator and my leader gave me IAM user account. What sholud I do and what do I need to request ? Please help me!

Comment: The user you assume while deploying your solution needs to have the rights to deploy the bucket. What you can do is assuming the role which has the correct permissions. You can try: `eval $(aws sts assume-role --role-arn <role_arn> --role-session-name tmp | jq -r '.Credentials | "export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\(.AccessKeyId)\nexport AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\(.SecretAccessKey)\nexport AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\(.SessionToken)\n"')`

Comment: Thanks for your care @Mornor I'm trying now.

Comment: @Mornor and Rishabh Sahrawat Thanks for your care. I attached role to my profile in ~/.aws/credentials file. Then I have solved S3:CreateBucket access denied error. Thanks for your help!